# Inconsitent behaviour -- Clicking on second radio button's label does not activate it, while first one does

Tags: html, radio-button

The code below (jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/)) is exhibiting a rather strange behaviour...

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="click_item" value="1" />
  <label for="one">First Item</label>
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="click_item" value="2" />
  <label for="two">Second Item</label>
</div>
```

... clicking on the label "First Item" checks/unchecks the first radio button, but clicking on the label "Second Item" does nothing!

I'm sure the solution is trivial, but I'm just not able to see what I'm missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` must be unique; you have the same ids. Correct this:

```
<input type="radio" id="two" name="click_item" value="2" />
```

Comment: Man! I can't believe I didn't see that.. this snippet was actually part of a larger code I'm debugging, and this one was driving me nuts! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have unique names of `id`, you are using the same id for both elements, so you need to declare another id for the other element, so it should be

```
<input type="radio" id="two" name="click_item" value="2" />
```

Comment: @maximkou: He probably didn't refresh his browser window to know you'd already answered..

Comment: @maximkou Why negative? and btw the other answer doesn't mention that ids should be unique

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I merged your answer with maximkou's. Thanks for pointing out that ids must be unique!